# Terraform conditional block inside a map

Tags: terraform, terraform-module

I have an [aws_lambda_function](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_function) resource like below:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "mylambda" {

    #...
    
    environment {
        variables = {
            FOO = 1
        }
    }

}
```

I'm tring to add some environment variables dynamically based on my `var.enable_vars`

```
variable "enable_vars" {
  type        = bool
  default     = false
}


resource "aws_lambda_function" "mylambda" {

    #...
    
    environment {
        variables = {
            FOO = 1
    #### if var.enable_vars == true
    #       BAR = 2
    #       BAZ = 3
        }
    }

}
```

How to achieve that? Is not clear to me if a `dynamic` block can be used there.

Comment: You could set the environment variables in the code itself from a file conditionally based on one variable set during the build time

Comment: @jabbson can you add more details?

Comment: you could have your environment variables stored in the .env files, uploaded along with the code and then loaded during execution. Also you could use ternary operator, if setting BAR = 0 or -1 could mean the same as not being set within your app logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be done with a `dynamic` block but its pretty complicated. This is how I would do it but there are other ways.

```
variable "enable_vars" {
  type        = bool
  default     = false
}

locals {
  default_lambda_vars = {
    FOO = 1
  }
  extra_vars = {
    BAR = 2
    BAZ = 3
  }

  final_lambda_vars = var.enable_vars ? merge(local.default_lambda_vars, local.extra_vars) : local.default_lambda_vars
}


resource "aws_lambda_function" "mylambda" {

    #...

    environment {
        variables = local.final_lambda_vars
    }

}
```